# Entire EBS not being used with AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I found out the entire root partition isn't used with the ami I created,

- ami 1: /dev/mapper/vg_basecentos6-lv_root 6.5G  2.0G  4.2G  32% /
- ami 2: /dev/xvde        20G  723M  18G  4% /

I've created the ec2 instance t2.micro with 20GB of storage

How do I make sure with ami 1 the entire disk is used as well?

Comment: So whats your question? Kobus.

Comment: Looks like you are using LVM. You probably need to extend the logical volume to cover the extra disk space. Google for details.